# Error inflating RecyclerView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to use a recyclerview in fragment but i got this error :
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

Main Activity :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Fragment fr;
            fr = new AuctionsList();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

     }
```

Fragment :

```
public class AuctionsList extends Fragment  {
    private List<Goods> goodsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GoodsAdapter mAdapter;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
      final View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.frg_auction_list, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new GoodsAdapter(goodsList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        prepareGoodsData();
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new GoodsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Goods good = goodsList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), good.getTitle() + " was clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



return rootView;
    }
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button android:id="@+id/but_terms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/main_but_terms"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/but_guide"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/main_but_guide"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/but_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:text="@string/main_but_login"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment android:name="com.ods.activity.AuctionsList"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView item xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="عنوان"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastBidPrice"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
           android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="356500"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remainingTime"
            android:layout_below="@id/lastBidPrice"
            android:textColor="@color/year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24:15:12"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add some code here. It's not clear what kind of problem you are facing here.

Comment: have you added the recycler view support to gradle?

Comment: I'm not using gradle! But I've added related libraries to project dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I should add whole RecyclerView library (Whole folder from Android SDK) to my modules as Library module and then add it as a dependency to my main project and adding it's jar library as well.